# force-attribute-nesting: why sasslint gives such warnings for my scss

Tags: sass, sass-lint

From the doc https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/blob/develop/docs/rules/force-attribute-nesting.md#force-attribute-nesting,

I changes

```
  a[title][href] {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

to

```
a {
  &[title][href] {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

But the sasslint stills warns, with

> Attribute-selector should be nested within its parent Attribute-selector (force-attribute-nesting)

Answer (score 2):

I'm just guessing, but I think you'd have to nest the two attributes separately, like so:

```
a {
  &[title] {
    &[href] {
      ...
```